# Can I let an swf communicate with a php file on another server?

Tags: php, database, actionscript-3, flash, cross-domain

I want to create an swf file for a client that sends data from textfields to a database on my server using php.

My code works fine when I upload it on my server, but I want to send the swf file to the client and have the swf communicate with the php file on my server.

What do I have to do to make this work? Is this possible even if I don't know the domain the client puts the swf on?

This is my as3 code:

```
// Assign a variable name for our URL Variables object
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

// Build the varSend variable
var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("databaseTest.php");
varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend.data = variables;

// Build the varLoader variable
var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler);


// Handler for PHP script completion and return
function completeHandler(event:Event):void{
    //clear the form fields
    name_txt.text = "";
    lastName_txt.text = "";
    mail_txt.text = "";
    status_txt.text = "Thanks";
}

// Add an event listener for the submit button and what function to run
submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ValidateAndSend);

// Validate form fields and send the variables when submit button is clicked
function ValidateAndSend(event:MouseEvent):void {

    // validate all the form fields
    if(!name_txt.length){
        status_txt.text = "name";
    }else if(!lastName_txt.length){
        status_txt.text = "last name";
    }else if(!mail_txt.length){
        status_txt.text = "mail";
    }else{
        // All is good so send the message to the parse file

        //Ready the variables for sending
        variables.comType = "parseInformation";
        variables.sendName = naam_txt.text;
        variables.sendLastName = achternaam_txt.text;
        variables.sendEmail = mail_txt.text;

        //Send the data to the php file
        varLoader.load(varSend);
    }
}
```

and this is the php code:

```
<?php

// Connect to MySQL database
mysql_connect("localhost","*******","********") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("*******") or die (mysql_error());

if($_POST['comType'] == "parseInformation") {
    $name = $_POST['sendName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['sendLastName'];
    $email = $_POST['sendEmail'];

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO databaseTest (name, lastName, mail)
    VALUES('$name', '$lastName', '$email')")
    or die (mysql_error());

    mysql_close();
    exit();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a file on the server where you place the php code.

it MUST be named crossdomain.xml and must be placed in the root directory of the server. In the file you can write the allowed domains:

```
<?xml version=”1.0″?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM “http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd”>
<cross-domain-policy>
        <allow-access-from domain="domain/IP address" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Or, as you don't know them, allow it to everyone:

```
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
```

(Avoid allowing access to everyone if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Here is detailed explanation from Adobe http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html

Please note that sometimes it's also necessary to allow headers in crossdomain.xml

```
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false">
```